# RegEx Jquery. Match whole word or fragment and extract whole word?

Tags: jquery, regex

How can i search either for whole word or in case of partial match extract whole word containing partial match?

Example: to match is "great";
String: "great greater."

It should match great and since greater contains great return whole word greater.

Comment: Thanks so much this works great matching towards the end. How to match whole word from the the start. like so: somegreater

Comment: I'm sorry i don't get it?

Comment: How would you match this: thisisgreater or great? In case of thisisgreater get whole word?

Comment: what do u think about this one??? ([^ ]*great[^ ]*)

Comment: https://regexr.com/62eo6 you would have to make it `([^ ]*?great[^ ]*?)` - try `(\w*great\w*)`  `[^ ]` (not space) is similar to `\w` where \w matches any "word character" but "not space" will also match tabs and other non-word characters.

Comment: Thanks so much yo guys. Your input helped me to get on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution for your problem.

```
const text = 'This is your sample message that is really messy.';
const pattern = /(\w*mes\w*)/gi;
const results = [...text.matchAll(pattern)];
console.log(results)
```

Here `\w` matches any alphanumeric symbol and an underscore, `*` matches that symbol 0 or more times (that means that you are waiting for an unknown number of symbols). Then `mes` is a substring that you are willing to find.
The `g` flag indicates that the regular expression should be tested against all possible matches in a string, and the `i` flag indicates that the matcher should ignore casing.